# Is there a way to debug to find out Maven is using the correct password while connecting to repository server?

Tags: maven

Trying to download `ojdbc` driver following [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides) , I have set master and repository server encrypted passwords in `.m2/settings-security.xml` and `.m2/settings.xml` but it still says Not authorized.I am wondering if decryption is getting to my intended password. Is there a way to debug or any other way to find out if Maven is using the correct password while connecting to repository server (`mvn -X compile` does not give this info).

pom.xml

```
...
  <repository>
    <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
    <name>oracle-maven-repo</name>
    <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
...
```

settings.xml

```
<settings>

<servers>
  <server>
    <id>maven.oracle.com </id>
    <username>....</username>
    <password>{....}

</password>
  </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

settings-security.xml

```
<settingsSecurity>
<master>{....}</master> 
</settingsSecurity>
```

Error on mvn compile

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Spring-Maven-Demo: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.maven.rea_spring:Spring-Maven-Demo:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:jar:18.3.0.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:jar:18.3.0.0: Could not transfer artifact com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:pom:18.3.0.0 from/to maven.oracle.com (https://maven.oracle.com): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Authorization Required. -> [Help 1]
```

**My debuging steps:**

1) confirming maven is reading `settings.xml`
`mvn -X compile`

```
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin\..\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\uname_x\.m2\settings.xml
```

2) confirming maven is reading `settings-security.xml`
Deleted all data from `settings-security.xml` throws error

```
[DEBUG] Failed to decrypt password for server maven.oracle.com: org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.SecDispatcherException:
```

3) I confirmed I am using the authorized credentials connecting manually.

Comment: For me the problem was that I forgot to add the <settings></settings> in the settings file

Answer (score 5):

`mvn help:effective-settings` shows the effective settings of the current environment including your location of settings.xml file.

`showPasswords=true` will help you see the passwords resolved as well if you are using environment variables.

```
mvn help:effective-settings -DshowPasswords=true
```

I had wasted a lot of time with -X option earlier.

Answer (score 1):

After checking your effective settings (as others have pointed out) with:

`mvn help:effective-settings -DshowPasswords=true`

I usually check the decrypted password - because I usually authenticate against repositories only over SSL/TLS - with something like:

`mvn clean package -Djavax.net.debug=plaintext`

And then look for the GET request (before it is encrypted) with its header:

`Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=`

You may want to decode that with something like:

`echo dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ= | openssl enc -d -a`

Which tells you the actual `username:password` sent to the server, amongst all other details of both the request and response.

For even more debugging goodness try `-Djavax.net.debug=all`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please run  `mvn` with --debug option. It should emit what the path is. Its possible that its not picking up the setting from your file.

Comment: Although I dont see debug info reading `settings-security.xml` I see info of reading `settings.xml` as in  `[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin\..\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\uname_x\.m2\settings.xml`. So I tried removing  `settings-security.xml` and run which throws `java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\uname_x\.m2\settings-security.xml`